# angularfirebase and typescript - set type for database returned value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function

```
 getPresence(userGuid: string): Observable<M.UserPresence>{
    let firebaseRef = this.firebaseService.getFirebaseUsersDataRef('presence/' + userGuid);
    return this.db.object(firebaseRef).valueChanges();
  }
```

the value that returns from the database is M.UserPresence. But, it's not compiling because

```
Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserPresence>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'UserPresence': status, timestamp
```

How can I "says" that the return type from the db is really M.UserPresence

Comment: Not familiar with firebase, but I may help. What's `this.db`? is there any generic version of `db.object`?